# React doesn't re-render when using React-Query's invalidateQueries

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

I'm new to `React-Query`.

And I'm using `useQuery` in `NextJS` to get user data.

Below is the code to change the nickname in the user data.

The problem is that when I change the nickname, it doesn't re-render with the changed nickname.
--> {user?.nickname}

```
export default function ProfileUpdateTest() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const { data: user } = useAuth();
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  return (
    <div>
      {user?.nickname}
      <Form.Control type="text" ref={inputRef} />
      <button onClick={test}>change nickname</button>
    </div>
  );

  function test() {
    axios.put('/api/user/nickname', { user_id: 3, nickname: inputRef.current?.value }).then(() => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(queryKeys.AUTH_USER);
    });
  }
}
```

```
export function useAuth() {
  const fetcher = () => request.get('/api/auth');
  return useQuery(queryKeys.AUTH_USER, fetcher, {
    select: (res): IUsers | null => {
      return res.data;
    },
  });
}
```

In React-Query Devtools, I checked the cache data changed.

Even using the `useMutation` hook, the result was the same.

Strangely, in other components it is shown with a changed nickname.

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that a QueryClient was newly created in the  component.

So I modified the code as below.

Before

`const queryClient = new QueryClient()`

After

`const [queryClient] = useState(() => new QueryClient())`

https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-fa-qs#2-the-queryclient-is-not-stable

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using **trpc** with **nextjs** and you have **ssr enabled**, you could try passing`queryClientConfig` instead of `queryClient`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).